# Iterate through lines of a text file and perform certain operations

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a test file with the following two lines of text:

```
( PIN  700_start_stop( STS_PROP( POS_X 123 )( POS_Y 456 )( BIT_CNT 1 )( 
CNCT_ID 7071869 ))(USR_PROP( VAR 1( Var_typ  -1 )(AssocCd H12 )( termLBLtmc  
+S))

( PIN  700_start_stop( STS_PROP( POS_X 123 )( POS_Y 456 )( BIT_CNT 1 )( 
CNCT_ID 7071869 ))(USR_PROP( VAR 1( Var_typ  -1 )(AssocCd H12 )( termLBLtmc  
+S))
```

They are stored in a text file called 'test.txt'

I am attempting to iterate through each individual line of a the text file and, using regex, push the info I want into a pandas dataframe(not a regex question, I have that). For some reason I can only ever get information from one line, not all. Below is the my thinking:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

with open(r'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Python Scripts\test.txt', 'r') as txt:

for each_line in txt:
    line=txt.read().replace('\n','') # convert line to type str

    re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
    re2='(\\d+)'    # Integer Number 1
    re3='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))' # Variable Name 1

    rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    m = rg.search(line)
    if m:
        int1=m.group(1)
        var1=m.group(2)
        print ("("+int1 + var1+")"+"\n")
        df1[df1.iloc(), 'Name'] = "("+int1 + var1+")"+"\n"
```

Ideally the print output of this file should be:

```
>>(700_start_stop)
>>(700_start_stop)
```

And the dataframe should look something like this:

```
 index          Name
   0     (700_start_stop)
   1     (700_start_stop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I looked over the code and wrote a simpler version.  It now works perfectly fine.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Name"])

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        line = line.strip()
        rg = re.compile(r'.*?(\d+[a-z_]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
        m = rg.search(line)
        if m:
            df1 = df1.append({"Name" : m[1]}, ignore_index=True)

print(df1)
```

Comment: This works. However, I don't want to make any changes to how I have implemented the regex, regardless of if it makes it easier or not. Do you know how to do achieve this? I am trying to work backwards from your solution but can't figure it out

Comment: Your regex is hard to read.  I use regex101.com to test regexes and splitting it up arbitrarily rarely helps improve readability (unless you have a 100 character long regex...).

Comment: .*? = non greedy operator, parenthesis denotes capture groups, and then the rest is pretty similar to what you had.

Comment: The m[1] is the same as m.group(1).

Comment: This is all for a proof of concept thing, the regex is gonna be like 50 characters long or so.

Comment: Is there a way to specify more than one group? i.e. m[1] AND m[2]?

Comment: `.*?(\d+)([a-z_]+)` using multiple sets of parenthesis creates more than one group.

Comment: Last small little question that is slightly unrelated. On the last line where you append to the df, is there another way to do this? I ask because I want to add different info to the same row, but append adds a new row right below it with the new column info.

Comment: You can add other columns by expanding the dictionary.  So instead of `"Name" : m[1]` do `"Name" : m[1], "age": m[2]`.

Comment: Oh wow amazing, I understand now and I think I have it figured out, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

the for loop over a file objcet loops over its lines. 
dont do that:

```
line=txt.read().replace('\n','')
```

discard that line and insted change :

```
m = rg.search(line)
```

to

```
m = rg.search(each_line)
```

"each_line" is the current line in each iteration of the file object.